# How do I link my extension to my Android app?

Tags: android, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

Chrome Web Store now shows links to Google Play for some apps and extensions:

http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2014/06/chrome-web-store-links-to-android-apps.html
[image]

Can anyone suggest me the configuration that needs to be done for this? Is the integration done on our side or on the Google side?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Quoting from [Francois Beaufort's G+ post](https://plus.google.com/100132233764003563318/posts/5fhFgvmAGYT) on this topic:

> If you're wondering how to get the experimental "available for
>   Android" link on the Chrome Web Store for your Chrome App/Extension,
>   you have to know that there is no way to enter this information into
>   your listing at this time.
>
> However, if the item names and developer email addresses match between
>   Play and CWS, there is a good chance your item will get this link
>   treatment the next time the script runs.