# Developer guide for Google Chrome extension development on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension

Recently Google chrome extensions on web store started appearing with - 'Available for Android' link which redirects to extension in play store. But unlike for [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android) on Android, there is no tutorial on how to develop and publish, Chrome extensions on Android. I would like to know two things.

1. Is any tutorial for Google chrome extension development in Android.
2. Do we need to upload extension in both Google web store and play store ? or How to publish extension such that it is available for Android in play store.

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/24116063/1180117. Should I delete this question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There is **still no way to make extensions for Chrome for Android**; those links go to native Android apps associated with the extension.

2) According to this [canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24126343/934239), linking Android app and Chrome Web Store item is done automatically in waves for matching apps, and you cannot influence the process.

Comment: Thanks. But how do those native apps access HTML DOM of Google Chrome ? Should I post it as separate query.

Comment: Definitely a new question; a good starting point would be [CCA toolkit](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps) for porting Chrome Apps to native, and other native apps use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) as fas as I know.

Comment: To reiterate, _extensions_ for Google Chrome (i.e. something that accesses a page open in Chrome) on Android are impossible at this time.