# Publishing to chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store, chromebook

I am in the process of publishing a hosted app to the chrome web store.  I have published my listing to a group of testers only.  When comparing my listing to other listings, I've noticed two differences.

When you click on some big name apps, for example Angry Birds, when the details open, underneath the title, you can see:

> star rating | app category | from SomeDomain.com | x,xxx,xxx users | available for Android Get It

I am unclear on how to modify some of these details.  Specifically, the third detail (from SomeDomain.com) and the last detail (available for Android)

My listing does have a "from SomeDomain.com" detail, but I want to modify it.  And my app's listing does not include an "available for Android" link.  I already have a publicly published Android app listed in google play.  I do not see where in the manifest, or in the google dev dashboard I can specify any of these details.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Regarding "from somedomain.com":

If you go to the edit page your listing, there's a drop-down called

> Verify that this is an official item for a website you own:

As long as you have the site you want verified on your developer account in the [Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home), you should be able to select a domain there.

### Regarding "available for Android":

There is currently no way to influence this. This is currently being added in sweeps by a script on the Google side.

See [this canonical answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24126343/934239). Criteria are a bit vague.

Comment: Following-up "from somedomain.com" I've noticed some apps seem to have a link there that could say anything. For example the Plex app displays, "from Plex, Inc" (and this text is a blue hyperlink) as opposed to "from www.plex.com" (plain text - no link).  Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know.

Comment: @tpdietz I think that happens when you _don't_ have a verified site. Then it's the developer name and links to the "website for the extension".

Comment: @Xan how do we get a custom name for a webapp published using the apps script console? Because, by defaul the dashboard alrady contains entries for the webapp's published URL and any of the developers blogspot blogs. There's not way to select "none" from that list of verified websites, so that your developer name could appear instead. any idea?

Comment: @Sujay Yes, it's impossible for a hosted app to not be bound to a website. It's only possible for packaged apps / extensions.

Comment: @Xan that sucks. thanks for the info. don't why why google has made the process of publishing webapps unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I mean I understand that (obviously) a hosted app has to be bound to a website (its own). however the chrome store listing could have a different link in the "offered by" to serve as a developer blog, etc.

Comment: @SujayPhadke Well, there are multiple links you can set for a webstore item.. The "link to website for your item" and "FAQ & support" one.

Comment: Yes, but when I set the link to my website, it "display" the link. but the underlying "targer" URL still points to the actual web-app URL, not my website. that's the problem. so its inconsistent.

Comment: @Xan I meant 'target' URL in my previous comment.